# SP2013 validate required fields before presaveaction

Tags: validation, newform

Is there a function that can be called in presaveaction that will do the preliminary SP required fields validation first?

For a simple example: A form has a start date and an end date, both required fields.

Before I do my presaveaction test that Start date < end date, I'd like to ensure that the fields have already been filled in as part of the standard SP required field validation testing.

Comment: Do you mean solution should validate the condition on change of end date like a client side validation?

Comment: No. I mean that I want all the inbuilt standard required field validation to be done before starting the presaveaction. Not related to any change event.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for run the build in validation prior to en presave action?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can think of is to write a script to look through the page to find all the fields that have the words "Required Field" in the title and see if there is any value assigned to it.

I don't think I have any inclination to do this. Perhaps an addition to jQuery one day?

Anyone keen enough could start with something like this:

https://www.mavention.nl/showing-required-fields-when-editing-a-page-sharepoint-2013/

The answer to How do I trigger the default form validation without submitting the form was that it could not be done.

Whilst not an ideal solution, future readers could look up [Save conflict - reset ratings and ratingscount in presaveaction](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/175143/save-conflict-reset-ratings-and-ratingscount-in-presaveaction)
... the use of window.onbeforeunload  may give inspiration.

Answer (score -1):

You can use PreSaveAction like the following:

```
<script language="javascript">
function PreSaveAction()
{
    //get your start and end date value
    //perform validation such as end date could not before start date
    return true;  // OK to proceed with the save item 
}
</script>
```

other useful URL:
http://chandanbadajena.blogspot.com.au/2011/09/add-javascript-date-validation-into.html

here also some other answer
[How do I trigger the default form validation without submitting the form](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/92864/how-do-i-trigger-the-default-form-validation-without-submitting-the-form)

Comment: No, these aren't solving the problem. THE REQUIREMENT IS: I do not want to have to validate that all the required fields have been supplied within the presaveaction. 
I want this inbuilt function to be done before presaveaction is called (or as a standard function that can be included at the start of the presaveaction function).